# Unable to update contract variables

Tags: solidity, web3js

I have this contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.20;

contract cntrct {
    uint public testVal;

    function runF() payable public
    {
        testVal += msg.value;
    }

    function reader() public view returns(uint)
    {
        return testVal;
    }
}
```

I know this contract doesn't make much sense but it is for testing purposes. So first I execute my javascript.

```
//SETUP
const fromAddr = '0x1...';
const toAddr = '0x2...'; //Contract
const contractName = ':cntrct';
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
const solc = require('solc');
const input = fs.readFileSync('Token.sol'); 
const output = solc.compile(input.toString(), 1);
const bytecode = output.contracts[contractName].bytecode;
const abi = JSON.parse(output.contracts[contractName].interface); 
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, toAddr);
contract.options.address = toAddr;

//DEPLOY
var deployed = contract
    .deploy({
      data: bytecode, 
      arguments: [[]]})
    .send({
      from: toAddr, //From the contract to the contract
      gas: 4700000, 
      gasPrice: '30000000000'}, 
    function(error, transactionHash) {console.log(error)});
```

Untill this point I assume everything went ok. The transaction showed up in the testRPC

```
Transaction: 0xa7ce099a9dd373e92d98ee34770f7db82329b25fd4a901c3fb90fd4f53221dd0
Contract created: 0x1df090c0785d203ad0f080a6f642eb3b8c0a7758
Gas usage: 118306
Block Number: 7
Block Time: Sun Mar 11 2018 09:41:39 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)
```

So now I want to send my first transaction and execute `runF()` with it.

```
//Create data to be send with the first transaction, 
// this step is crucial for my situation.
var data = web3.utils.sha3("runF()").substring(0, 10);

//Send the transaction
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    to: toAddr, 
    from:fromAddr,
    gasPrice: '30000000000', 
    gas: '50000',    
    data: data, 
    value: "1000000000000000000"}); //1 ether
```

The transaction shows up in the testRPC

```
Transaction: 0x939776bfedd6da6c9b2cb54b8149bdc2e0a70d331b3109331a26ee31937235de
Gas usage: 21272
Block Number: 8
Block Time: Sun Mar 11 2018 09:41:46 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)
```

And in remix I get these transaction details

```
from  0x1...
to    0x2... 
gas   50000 gas      
hash  0x939776bfedd6da6c9b2cb54b8149bdc2e0a70d331b3109331a26ee31937235de
input 0x9b4f5e44
value 1000000000000000000 wei
```

My final step is to call the `reader()` function.

```
contract.methods.reader().call().then(function(i){console.log(i)})
```

And this will output

```
Promise {
_bitField: 0,
_fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
_rejectionHandler0: undefined,
_promise0: undefined,
_receiver0: undefined }
> 0
```

When I click on the reader button in remix it states 0 as well. So my question is, why is my output still 0? I'm expecting it to be 1 ether because I have sent 1 ether and my contract should update the testVal to the sent value.

What I want to accomplish by doing it this way is that I want to publish the transaction data so anybody can execute my contract's function by sending ether + data from their own wallet, so without any UI that corresponds with the contract.

Comment: Is `run` defined somewhere? Seems like you want `data` there.

Comment: It is different in my case. I am getting my values updated. Did you try sending some ether when caling `runF`

Comment: @Ayushya Yes one ether, look at the `sendTransaction`. But I'm unsure if the `runF` function ever ran

Comment: @nona When doing all things via remix and metamask, it is working as you desire. I am able to send ether+data from metamask. And same I verified in remix. We are probably trying to find some error in js section.